# sending updates to clients with SignalR using publish-subscribe pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, signalr, publish-subscribe

I have some information that needs to be displayed to users in real-time. Before I had repetitive calls to the server for a fresh data.

Now I am thinking to replace these repetitive calls with SignalR. General idea is to subscribe on the client to the hub which will send updates to all clients when new entry will be added to a database, however I stuck there with general design of that structure.

So I have my WebAPI project and service layer. In the service when new entry is added I am going to raise an event and inside hub catch that event and send updates to all clients.

Is it a right way how these kind things achieved with SignalR? Can somebody explain how I can implement that given that I am using asp.net WebAPI and SimpleInjector.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Short answer: You can use SignalR for anything you need in live updating. Also, do your research into SignalR and how to implement/use it before asking SO `Can somebody explain how I can implement that ... `

Comment: @NewAmbition have you read my question carefully? I said that "I stuck there with general design of that structure", but not with the SignalR usage. Some examples that I found doesn't relevant in my case.

Comment: Could you possibly paste some code so people know your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways of designing pub / sub around SignalR

I created a wrapper for SignalR to solve it in a Event aggregation form

Please see the wiki

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Install using nuget

```
Install-Package SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy
```

See the demo project
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.MVC4

Comment: Thank you, that library seems quite neat, but how can I specify path for events script for instance to have "/api/eventAggregation/events"

Comment: Found that it is possible with using: 
            Bootstrapper.Init<BaseEvent>();
            MapExtensions.Map(_app, "/api/eventAggregation/events", subApp => AppBuilderUseExtensions.Use<EventScriptMiddleware<BaseEvent>>(subApp, new object[0])); instead of _app.MapEventProxy<BaseEvent>();

Comment: Spend a lot of time in order to make that working but no success. done almost everything the same that in example apart from IoC (using SimpleInjector but registered IEventAggregators as singletons) and that I have MVC and WebAPI apps so serverside logic is on WebAPI project but client stuff in MVC project, so events from server doesn't reach client for some reason..

Comment: Are the two in the same app domain? Your IEventAggregator implementation needs to be able to pick the evsnts up. My example only works in memory on the same app domain

Comment: Well it shouldn't matter because I have all server-side in WebAPI project in MVC I am only including client scripts to operate on a client side (jquery.signalR-2.0.3.js, /api/signalr/hubs, jquery.signalR.eventAggregator-1.2.99.0.js, api/eventAggregation/events). So SignalR by it self works fine with that design, but when I am calling signalR.eventAggregator.subscribe(MyNamespace.StandardEvent, function (data) { console.log(data); }, this); and then trying to raise event on a server side _eventAggregator.Publish(new StandardEvent("1")) it does nothing because handlers are empty.

Comment: And you having a server side listener that forwards the events to my library? Check every step in the wiki to see if you are missing a step

Comment: Did you mean EventAggregatorProxy or EventAggregator? I don't need server side listener. I subscribed listener on a client side and then on the server side I am publishing that event and expecting client side listener to be notified. Main problem is that EventAggregator.handlers are empty, however I can see that some data sent to the server about subscription {"H":"eventaggregatorproxyhub","M":"Subscribe","A":[[{"type":"MyNamespace.StandardEvent","constraintId":null}]],"I":0} but I cant see how handlers in EventAggregator are populated with client listeners. Maybe I need to set my IoC

Comment: You need to implement SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.EventAggregation.IEventAggregator and register it with SignalR. Check that the subscribe method of the interface fires. If it does that part works. You should now be able to publish events to SignalR using the Action delegate sent into the subscribe method

Comment: Finally, this was a problem. Thank you for your patience and help.

Answer (score 11):

PubSub patterns with signalR could be realized natively using groups.  Using the group name as topic, users can subscribe\unsubscribe by joining\leaving the group.

Here is the code snippets.  It is straight forward and it should scale out well.

```
[HubName("PubSub")]
public class PubSubHub : Hub {
    public void Publish(string topic, object data) {
        Clients.Group(topic).onNewMsg(topic, data);
    }
    public async Task Subscribe(string topic) {
        await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, topic);
        Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).onSubscribed(topic);
    }

    public async Task Unsubscribe(string topic) {
        await Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, topic);
        Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).onUnsubscribed(topic);
    }
}
```